# What makes a valid .mp4 video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player, metadata

I am downloading back to back some .ts video chunks from a website and saving them on the same file. When I try to upload this file to sites like twitter and facebook it doesn't accept it as a valid file. When I edit the file with ffmpeg, like the line below, it accepts it.

```
ffmpeg -i old.mp4 -metadata mediatype='video' new.mp4
```

I opened the new.mp4 file with a text editor and I saw this at the beggining:

```
\00\00\00 ftypisom\00\00\00isomiso2avc1mp41\00\00\00free\002\88mdat\00\00\AE\FF\FF\AA\DCE\E9\BD\E6\D9H\B7\96,\D8 \D9#\EE\EFx264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00\00\80\00\002]e\88\84\00\BF\89\E0^-}\9F\C6\CF\C5\E2\E4\BEbc仇zBM\FD\B6\E4
```

Is there a way to bypass the ffmpeg editing process and add some 'tag', some text, some bytes to the file that could make it a 'valid' video file?

Of course I tried to copy the first bytes from the new (the ffmpeg edited) to the old but it made it even worse (maybe I didn't know where to stop copying?), VLC can't even play it now. Before editing, the old.mp4 file could play on VLC, but with broken timestamp.

Also, there a big difference in size! old.mp4 is 6.4MB while new.mp4 is 3.4MB...

Comment: Randomly copying bytes from one place to another does not turn one file into a file with a different structure. Mp4 and ts will have different structures of blocks, headers, headers within blocks and so on. `ffmpeg` can copy video data from one "container" format to another without re-encoding the actual video data itself assuming that the video data is valid in the new container. The key part is `-c copy` which means "keep the codec(s) the same and copy data". ffmpeg builds the output stream per the mp4 specification with all the correct headers and so on. `.ts` is an MPEG Transport Stream.

Answer (score 2):

`.ts` files are not `.mp4` files.

Run `ffmpeg -i in.ts -c copy -movflags +faststart out.mp4` to generate a valid MP4.